# The progress bar preview of an MP4 video becomes a scary image

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

When I opened the video progress bar at 1:00 last night, the preview looked like this
I used the ffmpeg -I command to extract the video frame by frame and did not find this image
The progress bar preview returned to normal this morning, and the system time changed after the network was cut off was still normal until 1:00 a.m
I have no experience in video processing. How can I find this image?

[scary image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQvaD.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

In one second exists 1000 miliseconds, and yes, the scary image is between 00:00:12.001 - 00:00:12.999

First get a portion of video of 1 second of duration that start in 00:00:12.001 and ends in 00:00:12.999 (or may be can  be 00:11:27.001 - 00:11:27.999)

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:12.001 -i video_main.mp4 -t 0.999 minivideo.mp4
```

Test minivideo.mp4 that be 1 second duration

```
ffmpeg -i minivideo.mp4
```

It will to have this information:

> Duration: 00:00:01.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: xxxx

Now you can to extract 100 images for this 00:00:00.999 duration with "fps" parameter, getting 100 images per second (aprox),  fps=100/1, for 1000 per second 1000/1... etc., try

```
fmpeg  -i minivideo.mp4 -vf fps=100/1 -f image2 thumb-scary-%5d.jpg
```

If in the scary-%5d.jpg images thumbs donot appear the scary image, that will be a real horror movie, the cuco can appear and disappear into frames, jaja

Ok Let me know if the mistery was solved.

Regards

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it on my home.